# Jquery all selector(*) in chrome select scrollbars

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome

I have this code:

```
$("*").bind("mousedown.sg", { 'self':this }, this.sgMousedown);
```

It simple bind event listener on all elements at the page and it work correctly in all browsers except chrome. In chrome listener bind even on the scroll bar so that it stops responding to clicks.

The question is which selector can I use to avoid this ?

Comment: Have you tried `:not`?

Comment: Do you realize that you're binding an event handler to all elements of your page ? Why would you want this ?

Comment: I would try if I knew what element is scroll

Comment: Of course i realize. That the kind of element selector

Comment: Using * selector when biding events it's a big No No :). Try binding only the elements you need. If you really want to bind all of them use $("body *")

Comment: Use event bubbling! There is no need to add an event to every single element! That is a BAD design. `on()` is your friend here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what you're trying to achieve, but is binding to the body an option?

```
$("body").bind("mousedown.sg", { 'self':this }, this.sgMousedown);
```

Comment: very simple and very and very smart :)